# How to connect to mongodb EC2 instance, using JAVA Driver + SSH pem key

Tags: java, intellij-idea, amazon-ec2

Good afternoon.  I'm using Mongodb 2.6.7 + Java driver ( IntelliJ).

Presently i have cluster RF5 4 inst.+1arbiter.  I would like to connect to my primary using ssh, but  i don't have any idea how to do it...

to connect to local host i'm using - 
MongoClient client = new MongoClient( new ServerAddress("localhost", 27003)), but  how can i made connection to concert IP address using my xxx.pem key?

Thank You in advance, hope for quick reply

Answer (score 0):

You need to set-up an ssh tunnel. Once the tunnel is set-up, you can connect to your end of the ssh tunnel.

You can set-up the tunnel outsied of your application using the ssh client of your operating system. Or you can use a ssh java library like [JSCH](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) and set-up the tunnel from your java application.